# Error can not be cast activity when use Svgloder

Tags: android, svg, casting

In my adapter when i used svgloder for load .svg format photo i have some error please help?

```
    SvgLoader.pluck().with(G.context).load(cats.getImage(),holder.image);
```

and the error :

```
ir.vian_web.khezrpour.hadi.pezeshk_yab.G cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Comment: replace `G.context` to `context`.

Comment: it was activity not context

Comment: ok pass activity context to adapter from activity in constructor.

Comment: i used fragment

Comment: whatever, use `getActivity()` instead of this.

Comment: i do not understand please more Explain it

Comment: tanks for answer I solved it

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
SvgLoader.pluck()
                .with(context)
                .setPlaceHolder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .load(url, image);
```

Comment: paste your adapter here